# How can a body transition between soft and rigid during animation?

Tags: animation, physics

I would like to animate an object so that it transitions from being rigid to soft and back to rigid again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can control Soft Body stiffness during the animation, but I don't think that it's possible to change object physic 'on the fly'.

Comment: Stiffness would work, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As [LukeD](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29370/luked)'s comment suggested, you can animate the soft body stiffness.

I you want to key the rigid part yourself, use the [soft body goal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/settings.html#goal-settings) and animate its stiffness value.

[image: animate goal stiffness]

Resulting in a transition between manually keyed animation and soft body simulation.

[image]

You can also animate the [push and pull](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/settings.html#springs) for the Soft Body Edges. Here, I animated them from low values (0.2, 0.4) to 0.999.

[image]

As you can see, in them second example, the object's origin stays motionless as it has no animation.

[image]